# How to refresh model data from inside component in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

Currently I have a set up a application that lists the model collection and also have implemented pagination in it.

Now, I want to move all of this logic into a component so that it is reusable across multiple listings. To achieve this, I have passed the model variable inside the component.

Since, server data communication is considered a bad practice I assume the changes must be applied to the controller ?

So, I am confused on how to make the api call to refresh the data can be called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build method in controller and pass them as method in the required components. This way, you can avoid data call in component and make it reusable.

eg:

```
{{some-list getData=getSomeListData}}
```

where `getSomeListData` applies the required data changes.